# How can I update my flysky fs-i6?

Tags: transmitter, simulators, flysky

I bought a flysky simulator cable but my computer running Windows 10 won't recognize the transmitter when I plug it in. I even tried it using Arduino UNO and a Windows 7 PC but didn't work either.

Comment: I got it to work using arduino UNO and windows 11 pc.

Comment: Well, the simulator cable's job is to convert the DIN port's CPPM signal into a USB Joystick HID device for the computer to read. I would be surprised if it also serves as an adapter to use for updating the transmitter's firmware.

Comment: For example, (*and I haven't verified this method myself*) it appears that this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKkZpP55p9g) uses a dedicated firmware update adapter for this (https://www.amazon.com/Download-FS-GT6B-Transmitter-Controller-Firmware/dp/B07QKVDHP6)